Transformation of the plane of incidence denoted by its normal vector
In my simulation, I denote the plane of incidence by its unit normal vector calculated as the normalized cross product of the ray's direction $r$ and the surface normal $n$. Now, I want to apply a linear transformation $T$ to the scene, i.e. both surface and ray and want to relate the normal vectors of both planes of incidence also using a linear transformation.
I know that the cross-product transforms according to:
$$
(Tr)\times(Tn) = (\det T)(T^{-1})^T(r\times n)
$$
However, the transformed surface normal is actually $(T^{-1})^Tn$, making the above relation not usable. Unfortunately, my linear algebra is a bit rusty, and I failed at brute-forcing the equation.
To summarize: is there a transformation $M$ that solves the following?
$$
(Tr)\times((T^{-1})^Tn) = M(r\times n)
$$
In my case, any scaled version of $(Tr)\times((T^{-1})^Tn)$, including reversed ones would suffice.

This should not be possible in general as the LHS need not be antisymmetric in swapping $r,n$. You need to restrict to $T$ such that $(Tr)\times(T^{-T}n) = -(Tn)\times(T^{-T}r)$ for all $r,n$.
